# Finding the voltage gain at low frequencies

Tags: gain

can anyone explain how the second expression for the gain is obtained? 
they multiplied or divided the first equation and came up with second one.
[image]

Comment: The second equation cannot be correct.  The first 2 terms in the denominator, Rin and Rs, do not have the  same dimensions.

Comment: well, it is from the textbook.

Comment: @Barry the first two terms in the 2nd equation demoninator are Rin and R, s belongs to the second quotient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well something doesn't seem right here. I haven't checked the equation for \$V_g(s)\$, but starting from there, I can't arrive at the second equation:

We start with:
 $$ V_g(s) = V_i(s)\frac{R_{in}}{R_{in}+R+\frac{1}{sC_{C1}}} $$

Divide by \$V_i(s)\$:

$$ \frac{V_g(s)}{V_i(s)} = \frac{R_{in}}{R_{in}+R+\frac{1}{sC_{C1}}} $$

Pull out the term \$\frac{R_{in}}{R_{in}+R}\$
$$ \frac{V_g(s)}{V_i(s)} = \frac{R_{in}}{R_{in}+R}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{sC_{C1} (R_{in}+R)}} $$

Multiply by \$\frac{s}{s}\$:
$$ \frac{V_g(s)}{V_i(s)} = \frac{R_{in}}{R_{in}+R}\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{C_{C1} (R_{in}+R)}} $$

So either I'm doing it wrong, or the textbook has forgotten to remove the \$s\$ in the second denominator.

(English isn't my first language and I struggle with the names for basic mathematic operations, in German the last step would be "erweitern" and the step before "ausklammern")

Comment: You are right and the book is wrong.